# Regex to match digits with decimals that have spaces as well as no spaces

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex string to match a set of numbers:

1. 9.50 (numbers without spaces, that have 2 to 4 decimal points)
2. 1 9 . 5 0 (numbers with spaces that have 2 to 4 decimals points)
3. 10 (numbers without spaces and without decimal points)

So far I have come up regex string `[0-9\s\.]+`, but this not doing what I want. Any cleaner solutions out there?

Many Thanks

Comment: Is tab or new line a space as well?

Comment: Furthermore is the maximum 2-4 decimals?

Comment: Finally can you provide the programming language you use. Regexes have many dialects.

Comment: Are the numbers in the "set" separate strings, or would you also need the regex to match several "numbers" in one string? ex. "9.50 1 9 . 5 0 10"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that it will match `127.0.0.1` as well, which is an IP4 address, not a number.

The following regex should do the trick:

```
[0-9]+[0-9\s]*(\.(\s*[0-9]){2,4})?
```

Assumption I've made: You need to place at least one digit (before the comma).

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hD1kU5/1).

Comment: I appreciate the response. Doesn't match the whole number in the 1 set of numbers, just the decimals. Doesn't match the 3rd set of numbers as well. I'm looking for all sets to match

Comment: @B.Ng: can you give more test examples? All the given ones seem to match. Or specify better what should/shouldn't match.

Comment: I see what the issue is. I was using regexr.com. It didn't match the period in one of the sets for some reason. However, it worked when I tested it on regex101.com

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[\d\s]+(?:\.(?:\s*\d){2,4})?
```

This makes the decimal point and the digits/spaces after it optional. If there are digits after, it checks that there are 2-4 of them with `{2,4}`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eI3xO4/1)

If this should only match the whole string, you can anchor it.

```
^[\d\s]+(?:\.(?:\s*\d){2,4})?\s*$
```

Comment: I didn't notice that you posted something almost the same as  mine, I swear I came up with it myself :)

Comment: no problem, my comment was not meant offensive at all. +1 btw.

Comment: Sorry this is nit-picking, but this regex matches "1 1 . 2 3 6 7 4 5" which is more than 2-4 digits after the decimal. (I'm using PHP preg_match) Is it possible to count only the digits?

Comment: It matches `1 1 . 2 3 6 7`, the extra digits aren't part of the match.

Comment: `preg_match` just tells you if there's a match anywhere in the string. Since the regexp isn't anchored, extra things before or after it don't stop the match.

Comment: @Barmar, I did see that it captured the 4 digit portion instead of the full string. Is it possible to make the count only for the digits and ignore the spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The spaces are just optional allowed around the digits.

Comment: @Barmar, your edit with the anchored regex is what I was driving at. I was thinking the match should fail if strictly following the OP's requirements. Either way, your solution is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

`(\d+[\d\s]*\.((\s*\d){2,4})?|\d+)`

I was still getting "trailing spaces" selected with the third example of `10`

This eliminated them.

Comment: Awesome Kennah! It works great. I hadn't noticed the trailing spaces. Good thing you did. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't this work as well - `'[^. 0-9]'` ?

my full postgresql query looks like this:

```
split_part(regexp_replace(columnyoudoregexon , '[^. 0-9]', '', 'g'), ' ', 1)
```

and its doing the following:

1. values in the column get everything except numbers, spaces and point(for decimal) replaced with empty string.
2. split this new char string with `split_part()` and call which element in the resulting list you want.

was stuck on this for a while. i hope it helps.